# Does the following two pieces of Java for loop code yield the same result in every case?

Tags: java, for-loop

This question is regarding "sameEnds" problem of CodingBat Java section Array-2:

> Return true if the group of `n` numbers at the start and end of the array are the same. For example, with `{5, 6, 45, 99, 13, 5, 6}`, the ends are the same for `n=0` and `n=2`, and `false` for `n=1` and `n=3`. You may assume that `n` is in the range `0..nums.length` inclusive.

The CodingBat server passes code #2 for all cases including "other tests" but not code #1. Code #1 fails only for the so called "other tests". What are those other test cases for which code #1 fails? What is the difference between the two codes?

Code #1:

```
public boolean sameEnds(int[] nums, int len) {
  for (int i = 0; i < len && len > 0; i++, len--) 
    if (nums[i] != nums[(nums.length) - len]) return false;
  return true;  
}
```

Code #2:

```
public boolean sameEnds(int[] nums, int len) { 
  for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
    if (nums[i] != nums[nums.length - len + i]) return false; 
  return true; 
}
```

Comment: In code 1, the len > 0 check is actually not necessary. Since i is initially 0 and is being incremented. Therefore 0 <= i . Combine with the other check of i < len, and you have 0 <= i < len. Therefore 0 < len is always true given the other conditional and the behavior of i

Comment: Yeah, the two are ALMOST equivalent.  As others have indicated, the first loop terminates early, causing failures when len > nums.length / 2.  But this illustrate the hazards of trying to be "too cute".  Better to introduce another variable for Code 1, vs trying to do without.  Code 2 is more straight-forward, but even it might benefit from a separate variable for the second index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with Code 1 is that you're decrementing `len` each time, but still using it as your ending index for `i` in your `for` loop. Think about it... if `len` is initially 10, `i` will only count to 5, because 5 times through the loop, `i` will have incremented to 5 and `len` will have decremented to 5.

You could copy off `len` to a second variable used for your indexing, and use `len` only for checking `i` to end the loop. But personally I find your "Code 2" to be much more readable and clean anyway, so I would go with that.

Comment: @HotLicks Then the intent is for it to not work right? Think about it. In Code 1 the loop will run `len / 2` times. In Code 2 the loop will run `len` times. Both can't be right, and obviously Code 2 is the correct solution... [HotLicks keeps moving his comment, to which this is replying, around from answer to answer. I can't keep track and I'm not sure what he's getting at.]

Comment: Ah, that's what I was missing!  If the first loop terminates at len_start then they will be equivalent.

Comment: @DavidNorris I understood that len when used as a loop condition and  decremented will make the loop exit early as opposed to to using only len > 0 as the condition. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

No in first snippet of code, you are decrementing length. So if you have 10 items in collection it will iterate over first 5 items while second go to all 10 items.

Code 1:

```
public boolean sameEnds(int[] nums, int len) {
  for (int i = 0; i < len && len > 0; i++, len--) 
    if (nums[i] != nums[(nums.length) - len]) return false;
  return true;  
}
```

In upper code if len and nums.length are equal, then no need to pass as parameter, you may have a local copy be getting it from `nums.length` and to iterate or compare all items use:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < nums.length && len > 0; i++, len--)
```

code 2:

```
public boolean sameEnds(int[] nums, int len) { 
  for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
    if (nums[i] != nums[nums.length - len + i]) return false; 
  return true; 
}
```

In upper code I am assuming `len` is the length of `nums` array,

If Yes

- then I think there is no need to pass it as parameter as you can get
  within function by `nums.length`
- `nums.length - len` will always return 0 so no need to use this subtraction

If No:

- `nums[i]` may throw exception if len is greater than nums.length
- `if (nums[i] != nums[nums.length - len + i])` will always false

Comment: @HotLicks I'm confused. Why would 5 iterations be useless? Are you sure you understand the problem being solved?

Comment: I misread the question.  But the two appear to be equivalent.

Comment: Well, almost.  The loop terminating condition does bite you.

Comment: @Zaheer Ahmed Here len is the length of the sub array to be checked, which is always assumed to be less than nums.length. Hence it will not throw any exception. I think you didn't follow the specification properly. Anyway thanks a lot for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to `David Norris` and others who have responded to the question immediately. I learnt that when the for loop is framed like the following

```
i < len && len > 0; i++, len--
```

the loop according to `Code 1` terminates early as `len` value is being decremented with every iteration. So, considering the `Specification` and the test case

```
({1, 2, 5, 2, 1}, 5)
```

the loop terminates after only three iterations,

```
0 < 5 && 5 >0
1 < 4 && 4 > 0
2 < 3 && 3 > 0
```

where it is supposed to iterate for 5 times and check the **entire sub-array**. This is the reason why the `codingbat` server is not accepting the `Code 1` as the exact answer.

I have fixed the `Code 1` like the following and the `codingbat` server has accepted the solution as the correct answer.

**Corrected Code 1:**

```
public boolean sameEnds(int[] nums, int len) {
  for (int i = 0; len > 0; i++) {
    if (nums[i] != nums[(nums.length) - len]) return false;
    len--;
  }
  return true;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that in Code 1 you change your condition ('i < len') inside a loop by decreasing it. You could make a copy of 'len' to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean sameEnds(int[] nums, int len) {
    if (nums.length > 1 && len > 0)
    {
        if (nums[len-1] == nums[nums.length-1])
        {
            return true;
        }

    }
    if (len == 0 || nums.length == 1) return true;
    return false;
 }
```

Comment: Please explain your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using strings.

```
public boolean sameEnds(int[] nums, int len) {
    //Create 2 blank strings.
    String testOne = "";
    String testTwo = "";
    //For the amount of len, we make strings starting from each side, and ending at len
    //inwards.
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
      //testOne is for the left side.
      testOne = testOne + String.valueOf(nums[i]);
      //testTwo is for the right side.
      testTwo = String.valueOf(nums[(nums.length - 1) - i]) + testTwo;
    }
    //If they equal, return true. If they don't, return false;
    return (testOne.equals(testTwo));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution, comparing two arrays:

```
public boolean sameEnds(int[] nums, int len) {

    int length = nums.length;
    int[] arr = new int[len];

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr[i] = nums[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] != nums[i+length-len]) return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help as well.

```
public boolean sameEnds(int[] nums, int len) {
    //  Creating two arrays A & B to store first and last (len) numbers
    int[] arrA = new int[len];
    int[] arrB = new int[len];
    
    // Storing first set of integers in arrA
    for(int i = 0; i <len; i++) {
        arrA[0] = nums[i];
        // System.out.print(arrA[0]);
    }
    // Storing second set of integers in arrB
    int pos = 0;
    for (int j = (nums.length)-len; j < (nums.length); j++) {
        arrB[pos] = nums[j];
         // System.out.println(arrB[pos]);
    }
    // Comparing and returning boolean values
    return Arrays.equals(arrA,arrB);
```

}

Answer (score -1):

```
    public boolean sameEnds(int[] nums, int len) {

    boolean b = true;

    if (len == 0) {
        b = true;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {

        if (nums[i] != nums[nums.length - len + i]) {

            b = false;
            break;
        }

    }

    return b;

}
```

Comment: I am new in stackoverflow  . help me with your suggestion to improve the answer.